# Any experiencing errors upgrading to 4.7.9, related to 'CRM-16189 Financial account relationship'

Tags: upgrade

My upgrade simply hangs (20+ minutes) and then crashes a 2GB VPS trying to execute the MySQL related to 4.7.9.

My guess is that line 26 and beyond in 4.7.9.mysql.tpl is writing checks that my server cannot cash, given over 100,000 contributions already in Civi.

Can this query be optimized or can I see a less smarty-ized version of it I can run?  What are the consequences of not running these queries, if we do not use Accounting integration or Financial Accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found it was the FK changes in 4_7_8 in FourSeven.php in conjunction with the 4.7.8.mysql.tpl were crashing server.  By commenting out all 4.7.8.mysql.tpl and then manually running these after upgrade complete, there were no crash/hang.